# Return the first non empty/blank value?

Tags: clojure

I have 2 bindings I'm calling path and callback.

What I am trying to do is to return the first non-empty one. In javascript it would look like this:

```
var final = path || callback || "";
```

How do I do this in clojure?

I was looking at the "some" function but I can't figure out how to combine the compjure.string/blank check in it. I currently have this as a test, which doesn't work. In this case, it should return nil I think.

```
(some (clojure.string/blank?) ["1" "2" "3"])
```

In this case, it should return 2

```
(some (clojure.string/blank?) ["" "2" "3"])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(first (filter (complement clojure.string/blank?) ["" "a" "b"]))
```

*Edit:* As pointed out in the comments, `(filter (complement p) ...)` can be rewritten as `(remove p ...)`:

```
(first (remove clojure.string/blank? ["" "a" "b"]))
```

Comment: Would `(first (remove clojure.string/blank? ["" "a" "b"]))` work?

Comment: Another way of writing it: `(first (filter not-empty ["" "a" "b"]))`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are so lucky to have "empty values" represented by nil and/or false you could use:

```
(or nil false "2" "3")
```

Which would return `"2"`.

An equivalent to your JavaScript example would be:

```
(let [final (or path callback "")]
  (println final))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would use the `some` function:

```
(some #(when-not (empty? %) %) ["" "foo" ""])
"foo"
(some #(when-not (empty? %) %) ["bar" "foo" ""])
"bar"
```

As others have pointed out, `filter` is another option:

```
(first (filter #(not (empty? %)) ["" "" "foo"])
"foo"
```

A third option would be to use recursion:

```
(defn first-non-empty [& x]
  (let [[y & z] x]
    (if (not (empty? y))
      y
      (when z (recur z)))))

(first-non-empty "" "bar" "")
"bar"
(first-non-empty "" "" "foo")
"foo"
(first-non-empty "" "" "")
nil
```

I used `empty?` instead of `blank?` to save on typing, but the only difference should be how whitespace is handled.

Comment: You can save yourself a level of parentheses and use `when-not` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first non blank string of a sequence you can use something like this:

```
(first (filter #(not (clojure.string/blank? %)) ["" "2" "3"]))
```

This will return 2

What i don't understand is your first example using the some function, you said that it should return nil but the first non blank string is "1".

Answer (score 1):

It was difficult for me to tell exactly what you wanted, so this is my understanding of what you are trying to do.

In my case, I wanted to find if an item in one report was missing in a second report. A match returned nil, and a non-match returned the actual item that did not match.

The following functions wind up comparing the value of a mapped value with a key.

Using something like `find-first` is probably what you want to do.

```
(defn find-first 
  "This is a helper function that uses filter, a comparision value, and
   stops comparing once the first match is found. The actual match
   is returned, and nil is returned if comparision value is not matched."
  [pred col]
  (first (filter pred col)))

(defn str-cmp
 "Takes two strings and compares them. Returns 0 if a match; and nil if not."
 [str-1 str-2 cmp-start-pos substr-len]

 (let [computed-str-len (ret-lowest-str-len str-1 str-2 substr-len)
  rc-1 (subs str-1 cmp-start-pos computed-str-len)
  rc-2 (subs str-2 cmp-start-pos computed-str-len)]

  (if (= 0 (compare rc-1 rc-2))
   0
   nil)))

(defn cmp-one-val
"Return nil if first key match found, 
 else the original comparision row is returned.
 cmp-row is a single sequence of data from a map. i
 cmp-key is the key to extract the comparision value.
 cmp-seq-vals contain a sequence derived from 
 one key in a sequence of maps.
 cmp-start and substr-len are start and stop 
 comparision indicies for str-cmp."

 [cmp-row cmp-key cmp-seq-vals cmp-start substr-len]
 (if (find-first #(str-cmp (cmp-key cmp-row) %1 cmp-start substr-len) cmp-seq-vals)
  nil
  cmp-row))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what you're accomplishing here. In the javascript version, I have n+1 variables. I want to return the first that is not blank or return an empty string if all are blank

Comment: Where is find-first defined? I don't see it in core.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for catching the missing function.